# Title bar doesn't include dropdown (CSS)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I can't get the dropdown to align in the same row as the rest of the bar (code below). I tried working with margins and paddings but that doesn't help either. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I need the drop-down menu to be on the right corner of the bar. You don't have to do the code for me, but I am trying to figure if there are two different styles intersecting each other and causing this or what should I do next?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "Verdana";
}

.headDivider {
  background-color: #ff7200;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 63px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.back {
  border-radius: 13px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #7c7c7c;
  padding: 10px 26px 10px 26px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 95px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.topText {
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 270px;
  color: #ff7200;
}

.bottomText {
  line-height: 280px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #ff7200;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="headDivider">
    <button type="button" class="back">Back</button>
    <h4 class="title"> Viking Vote + </h4>

    <div class="dropdown" style="text-align:right;">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="headDivider">

     <div style="float:left;">

         <table>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="back">Back</button>
                 </td>
                 <td>   
                     <h4 class="title"> Viking Vote + </h4>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>            

     </div>
     <div style="float:right;">

         <table>
             <tr>
                <td>
                     <div>
                         <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                     </div> 
                 </td>
                 <td>       
                     <div class="dropdown" style="text-align:right;">

                         <div class="dropdown-content">
                             <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                             <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                             <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>

    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap can also get you there using its row feature

Answer (score 0):

As one of the variants is to use flexbox for headDivider

```
.headDivider {
  background-color: #ff7200;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 63px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 3px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jjtpta4/) with this solution and small fixes for other elements